# Update the value of a field on UPDATE of another IF it equals a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have one field in a table and I'm updating it often; what I want to do is if when that field is updated it equals the same value of another field then update another field.

Let me explain, basically a quicker way of doing this:

```
UPDATE my_table SET spots_taken=spots_taken+1 WHERE id=1234;

UPDATE my_table SET open=1 WHERE id=1234 AND spots_taken=spots;
```

Can this be done in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `CASE`:

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET spots_taken=spots_taken+1,
    open = (CASE WHEN spots_taken=spots THEN 1 ELSE open END)
WHERE id=1234
```

Comment: @Brett: Did you check it?

Comment: Yep, just did. Worked well! Thanks!